# Why does Page Inspector display unwanted <$A$> tags

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, page-inspector

I'm using the page inspector debugger in Visual Studio to compete a tutorial on how to use jQuery to display a dialog showing a line of text and a dropdownlist.

In Page Inspector it appears with random ,  tags around the elements as shown

[image]

This doesn't happen when it it debugged in Chrome, IE etc

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this before, or have ideas why it might be occurrng.  Is this just a 'feature' or the Page Inspector?

The code used to generate this popup is as follows...

This works by pressing the button `btnLookAndFeel` on page `ItemEdit.cshtml` which calls the `ListingItemController.EditLookAndFeel` method, which returns the partial view `EditLookAndFeel.cshtml`

**ItemEdit.cshtml**

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#btnLookAndFeel').click(function () {
                $.get('/ListingItem/EditLookAndFeel',
                    { id: $('#LookAndFeelId').val() },
                    function (data) { $('#divLookAndFeel').html(data).dialog(); });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**ListingItemController.cs**

```
public ActionResult EditLookAndFeel(int id)
    {
        var list = _lookAndFeelService.List();
        ViewBag.LookAndFeelList = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Name", id);
        return PartialView();
    }
```

**EditLookAndFeel.cshtml**

```
<div>
    Please select the Look and Feel: @Html.DropDownList("LookAndFeelList") 
</div>
```